# Type 'EmployeeService[]' is not assignable to type 'Employee[]'

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm a newbie Typescript, I have below component:

```js
export class EmployeeService {
  private baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/api/v1/employees';

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  getEmployeeList(): Observable<EmployeeService[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<EmployeeService[]>(`${this.baseUrl}`);
  }
}

export class EmployeeListComponent implements OnInit {
  employees: Employee[];

  constructor(private employeeService: EmployeeService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getEmployee();
  }

  private getEmployee() {
    this.employeeService.getEmployeeList().subscribe((data) => {
      this.employees = data; //got error here
    });
  }
}
```

Below is error:

```
Type 'EmployeeService[]' is not assignable to type 'Employee[]'.
Type 'EmployeeService' is missing the following properties from type 'Employee': id, firstName, lastName, emailIdts(2322)
(property) EmployeeListComponent.employees: Employee[]
```

Thank you for any response.

Comment: EmployeeService[] -> Why EmployeeService is mentioned as an array

Answer (score 1):

```
getEmployeeList(): Observable<EmployeeService[]> {
  return this.httpClient.get<EmployeeService[]>(`${this.baseUrl}`);
}
```

You've set here that this observable is going to emit an array of `EmployeeService`s. Not `Employee`s, entire services. Since this is an http request, typescript doesn't know what data will be returned, so it can't verify whether that's correct and will trust what you say. Then later when you try to assign what typescript thinks is a `EmployeeServices[]` to a `Employee[]`, you get the error.

The likely fix is change it to:

```
getEmployeeList(): Observable<Employee[]> {
  return this.httpClient.get<Employee[]>(`${this.baseUrl}`);
}
```